# Jacoco: Testing @Data annotation in Unit Testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jacoco

After running test and generating coverage report via Jacoco, I realized that there is a static method where a `@Data` annotation is used and the line of it is marked yellow indicating that it is not tested.

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvqo6.png)

So, is it normal or how can I test that line?

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get so much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: @RF1991 Chico, I just wondered why Jacoco displays the `@Data` line as if it is not tested. Because I generally look at the method block as I have never seen it points annotation as not tested. So, you do not need code, just let me know what it means?

Comment: Don’t worry about coverage, just write some good tests.

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang You right, but as I am beginner, I am trying to know some details to write good test :) I think, maybe it is related to static method.

Comment: @Chico_RF1991 Any idea about last situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jacoco can ignore code generated by lombok.

put `lombok.config` in your project’s root

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

- jacoco Release 0.8.0 (2018/01/02)

  - Methods annotated with @lombok.Generated to better integrate with Lombok >= 1.16.14. Initial analysis and contribution by Rüdiger zu Dohna (GitHub #513).
  - Methods annotated with @groovy.transform.Generated to better integrate with Groovy >= 2.5.0. Thanks to Andres Almiray for adding the annotation to Groovy (GitHub #610).
- jacoco Release 0.8.2 (2018/08/21)

  - Classes and methods annotated with annotation whose retention policy is runtime or class and whose simple name is Generated are filtered out during generation of report (GitHub #731).

Answer (score 0):

Seems opinion based, but in my opinion there is no point for testing generated code from an external dependency. I would do noting about it and move on.

Comment: Thanks amigo, but it is not opinion based. When some user have no idea for any question, they generally start to blame the question as if it was opinion based. So, maybe no need to worry for the yellow line, but I think there must be sign for a problem or warning. Any idea?

Comment: @stack `@Data` generates a lot of code: getters, setters, hashCode, equals and so on. If I were you and wanted to get it "green" I would try to execute all of them to check if that makes a difference. Starting with a simpler class with only @Getter is in my opinion the way to go.

Comment: Yes, this would be a proper way. Thanks a lot chico, marked as answer!